# Adding a UIPickerView inside UIActionSheet in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I've a UIPickerView and need to make it show inside a UIActionSheet in iPad (it works very straightforward in iPhone, not in iPad).

I've a button on the View when I click on I execute the following code:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I am pressed");

    UIPickerView* picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,500,500)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:picker];    
}
```

// the PickerView delegate and datasource functions:

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return @"One";
}
```

But When change the above code to add the PickerView inside an actionSheet, **It shows only the header of the ActionSheet but without the PickerView inside it!**

The modified code as follows:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"I am pressed");

    UIActionSheet* actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"My PickerView"
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIPickerView* picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,500,500)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];
    [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 469) inView:self.view animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stuck, I gonna use a `UIPopoverController` with a `UITableViewController` inside instead! .. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the frame of the picker. (100, 200) on (x, y) might not be a good position.

Comment: When I changed the pickerView initLine to `UIPickerView* picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,469)];` I can now see very tiny part of the the PickerView inside the ActionSheet but the actionSheet is shown as a very small square, How can I make it bigger, I am trying changing its width and height but seems not working!

Comment: Try to set the cancelButtonTitle to some NSString to see if the size changes.

Comment: I sucks, I gonna use a `UIPopoverController` with a `UITableViewController` inside instead! .. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -4):

I think the line `([actionSheet addSubview:picker];)` should be
`[actionSheet addSubview:picker.view];`
I was having the same issue but using `UIWindow`.

Comment: `UIPickerView` inherits from `UIView`; it does not have a property, `view`, of its own.